# Integrate UI path with Power automate

Tags: power-automate, uipath

Is it possible to integrate UI path code into Power Automate workflow( dreceive data from microsoft (eforms) )

In terms of what i want to do is insert json file (uipath) into power automate code to continue the task of the robot which is logon on to help desk platform and log a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need.

Possible solutions I can see:

1. You control Forms with the robot completely via Web browser. Simply download the Forms export there.
2. You must first open the URL “https://forms.office.com/Pages/DesignPage.aspx” to obtain a token. Then you can call "https://forms.office.com/formapi/DownloadExcelFile.ashx?formid=" + put your form ID Here + "&timezoneOffset=180&minResponseId=1&maxResponseId=1000".
3. Use Power Automate and download the report to something like OneDrive or any other file share and use it in your UiPath process.

Comment: Well, this info is missing in your question. Please edit your question so that also others know what your concerns are. Thanks.